Choosing the initial seed point in Newton Raphson method
In Newton-Raphson method to find approximate roots I noticed 2 approaches being followed to choose initial seed points for a given equation f(x) and I am confused when to apply which method.
First approach
Assume some $x=0,1,2,.....$ and we find some $x_{a}$ and $x_{b}$ such that $f(x_{a}) < 0$ and $f(x_{b}) > 0$ and hence our root lies between $[x_{a}, x_{b}]$. Now we choose $x_{0}$ i.e. our initial seed as the one among $x_{a}$ or $x_{b}$ which is has $f(x)$ values nearer to 0 i.e. whichever has the minimum absolute value among $f(x_{a})$ and $f(x_{b})$.
In a case of both having same absolute values for $f(x)$ we can pick any one among $x_{a}$ or $x_{b}$ as the initial seed point $x_{0}$.
Questions where this approach is followed as per my observation:-
Q1. Find smallest positive root of $3x^3 - 9x^2 + 8 = 0$ correct to 4 places of decimal using Newton Raphson method.
(Solution : here $f(1) = 2 $ and $f(2) = -4$ and $x_{0}$ is chosen to be 1)
Second approach
Assume some $x=0,1,2,.....$ and we find some $x_{a}$ and $x_{b}$ such that $f(x_{a}) < 0$ and $f(x_{b}) > 0$ and hence our root lies between $[x_{a}, x_{b}]$. Now we choose $x_{0}$ i.e. our initial seed as the midpoint among $x_{a}$ and $x_{b}$ i.e. $x_{0} = \frac{(x_{a} + x_{b})}{2}$.
Questions where this approach is followed as per my observation:-
Q1. Find root of $e^x = 2x + 1$ correct to 4 places of decimal using Newton Raphson method.
(Solution : here $f(1) = -0.28 $ and $f(2) = 2.39$ and $x_{0}$ is chosen to be 1.5)
Clarification
Mostly I find its mentioned that choice of seed determines faster convergence. Now my question is how to determine which method to follow in order to reduce the number of iterations in finding the root correct to given decimal places.
(Did check other articles on stack exchange but could not clarify this doubt, would be helped if someone explains me the difference and appropriate choice in a simple way since I am a new to this topic, pardon me for any mistakes)

The answer is given by Darboux theorem.
Select $x_0$ such that
$$f(x_0)\times f''(x_0) >0$$
If this condition is satisfied, the convergence to solution will be monotonic (no overshoot furing the path).
Try it with your cubic equation.

Thanks for replying and providing a resource for the same although I am not being able to translate the book so easily.
Well I get to know this condition now, but my actual question was like which pathway to follow for choice of $x_{0}$ after I find the interval where my root lies, whether to select the one closer to 0 or simply find the midpoint.
Can you please advice me regarding the same.

Even if in French, it is easy to read. For your question, what I wrote is sufficient. Just check thé condition at thé bounds and select the appropriate one
